# Replacing the keys in a dictionary based on the values of another

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries (Dic1 and Dict2)

```
Dict1 = {'M0': 399, 'M1': 71, 'M2': '0.979827269', 'M3': '0.84576281', 'M4': '0.011849132', 'M5': '0.066588785'}
Dict2 = {'M0': 'KPI1', 'M1': 'KPI2', 'M2': 'KPI3', 'M3': 'KPI4', 'M4': 'KPI5', 'M5': 'KPI6'}
```

I want to update the keys of Dict1 based on the key-value pairs in Dict 2.
So I want my output dictionary to look like

```
Dict1 = {'KPI1': 399, 'KPI2': 71, 'KPI3': '0.979827269', 'KPI4': '0.84576281', 'KPI5': '0.011849132', 'M5': '0.066588785'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension to create a new dict.

```py
res = {Dict2[k] : v for k, v in Dict1.items()}
```

Comment: You can assign the result back to `Dict1` if you want to change that variable: `Dict1 = {Dict2[k] : v for k, v in Dict1.items()}`

Comment: Although keys in dictionaries are required to be unique, the values certainly are not.  Keep in mind that `Dict2` must contain unique values for this solution to work.  If they are not unique, the answer will not be what is expected.  For example, `d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}` and `d2 = {'a': 'A', 'b': 'B', 'c': 'A'}` results in `{'A': 3, 'B': 2}` using this solution.  I'm not criticizing the solution, just raising the issue that the OPs question can only be answered if the values in the second dictionary are guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: Moreover, if `Dict2` somehow does not contain a key from `Dict1`, this code will raise an exception.